# Discord.py slots command add moving animations of emojis

Tags: python, discord

I'm making a Discord bot with Python that's basically an all-in-one bot. One of the features it has is a slot machine system, as part of its economy system. I have already worked out all the logic for the slot machine. My code is really long, so I'm only going to show the slot machine's function:

```
@bot.command(name="slots")
async def slots(ctx, amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Kid you gotta bet some actual omegas (bob's currency)")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

    amount = int(amount)
    if amount > bal[0]:
        await ctx.send("Imaginary omegas don't work here sunny boi, you don't have enough omegas for that transaction")
        return
    if amount < 0:
        await ctx.send("Did ya ever learn about money in school? Give a positive value")
        return
    
    final = []
    for i in range(3):
        a = random.choice([":apple:", ":banana:", ":watermelon:"])
        final.append(a)

    for i in final:
        realfinal = str(final).replace("[", " ")

    for j in realfinal:
        realREALfinal = str(realfinal).replace("]", " ")

    for k in realREALfinal:
        absfinal = str(realREALfinal).replace("'", " ")

    for l in absfinal:
        finalfinal = str(absfinal).replace(",", " | ")

    slotem = discord.Embed(title=str(finalfinal), color=0xff9966)
    slotem.add_field(name="SLOT MACHINE", value="Let's see if ya win kid")
    await ctx.send(embed=slotem)
    if final[0] == final[1] or final[0] == final[2] or final[1] == final[2]:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, 2*amount, "pocket")
        slotwinem = discord.Embed(title=f"Good job kid, you won `Ω{2*amount}`", color=0xccff66)
        await ctx.send(embed=slotwinem)
    elif final[0] == final[1] == final[2]:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, 3*amount, "pocket")
        slotallwinem = discord.Embed(title=f"Wow, sweet victory kid, you got `Ω{3*amount}`", color=0xccff66)
        await ctx.send(embed=slotallwinem)
    else:
        await update_bank(ctx.author, -1*amount, "pocket")
        slotloseem = discord.Embed(title=f"Oooh, tough luck kid- you lost `Ω{amount}`", color=0xff3300)
        await ctx.send(embed=slotloseem)
```

This code is definitely extremely inefficient, but it works for now. What I want to do is for the slot machine to look like a real slot machine. To be more specific, I want the embed to be edited so all the emojis look like they are scrolling through all the choices. After two seconds, the first emoji scrolling stops and falls into place. After another two seconds, the second emoji falls into its place. After another two seconds, the third emoji falls into place. For example, this is a visual representation of what I mean: https://th.bing.com/th/id/Rd55e38b55c9ae007a4ffa1c5616bccd5?rik=iQ6wFZblIMc4pQ&pid=ImgRaw

How could I replicate this in Discord.py? Thanks.

Comment: This works with GIFs/animated emojis that you store somewhere.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: You can store them somewhere, define them and then choose 3 random ones.